# TSQL: How to Join / Combine rows of a single column into a CSV list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-group-concat

I have a table called "colamer" as shown below:

```
ID    Title   SectionID
1      abc     231
2      abc     232
3      pqr     95
4      jkl     165
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckDuplicateBannerforSection  
/*
      colamer_CheckDuplicateBannerforSection 'abc','231,232,233',NULL
*/

@BannerTitle NVARCHAR(200),        
@SectionId VARCHAR(50),        
@Result VARCHAR(100) OUT        
AS        
BEGIN        
 SET @Result = 1        
   BEGIN  
        IF EXISTS        
    (SELECT 1 FROM colamer WHERE Title= @BannerTitle   
 And SectionID in(SELECT value FROM dbo.colamer_fn_Split1( @SectionId ,',')))   
   END  
SELECT @Result
```

END

I want the OutPut:
@result = 231,232

Comment: What does the function `dbo.colamer_fn_Split1` do?

Comment: Save yourself the effort of replying, I figured it out. :)

Comment: it splits the string,,

Comment: @Pranav In your example title `abc` have only one SectionID 231 then how can you fetch 231,231 as output. Please clarify...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckDuplicateBannerforSection  
/*
      Mercola_CheckDuplicateBannerforSection 'abc','231,232,233',NULL
*/

@BannerTitle NVARCHAR(200),        
@SectionId VARCHAR(50),        
@Result VARCHAR(100) OUT        
AS        
BEGIN  
   SELECT @Result = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), c.SectionID)
                           FROM colamer c
                           CROSS APPLY dbo.colamer_fn_Split1(@SectionId, ',') AS A 
                           WHERE c.SectionID = A.value AND Title = @BannerTitle   
                           FOR XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, ''
                         )            
END
```

Comment: Why use `CROSS APPLY`? It is not necessary. The original `IN` list was fine, or an `INNER JOIN` would work.

Comment: Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Comment: This'll work because the characters will always be only numbers, but if you use this `xml path('')` method for textual data, it could mess up characters that need xml-entities like `&amp;`. Solve this by doing `stuff((select [...] for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')` (Note the **, type** and **.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')**)

Comment: @saharsh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936466/merge-2-or-more-rows-of-a-column-if-other-column-has-same-values-text-in-sql-ser

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckDuplicateBannerforSection  

@BannerTitle NVARCHAR(200),        
@SectionId VARCHAR(50),        
@Result VARCHAR(100) OUT        
AS        
BEGIN        
  SET @Result = ''          
  Select @Result = @Result + ',' + Convert(nvarchar, SectionID)
  from colamer where Title = @BannerTitle and SectionID in(SELECT value FROM dbo.colamer_fn_Split1( @SectionId ,','))  
END
```

Comment: Yes that was redundant, see the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Mercola_CheckDuplicateBannerforSection  
/*
      Mercola_CheckDuplicateBannerforSection 'abc','231,232,233',NULL
*/

@BannerTitle NVARCHAR(200),        
@SectionId VARCHAR(50),        
@Result VARCHAR(100) OUT        
AS        
BEGIN        
 SET @Result = 1        
   BEGIN  
 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM colamer
             WHERE Title = @BannerTitle   
            And SectionID 
           in(SELECT value FROM 
             dbo.colamer_fn_Split1( @SectionId ,',')))   
BEGIN
    SELECT top 1 @Result=SectionID FROM colamer
    WHERE Title = @BannerTitle   
    And SectionID in(SELECT value FROM 
    dbo.colamer_fn_Split1( @SectionId ,','))
END
   END  
SELECT @Result  

END
```

Comment: output should be 231,232

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936466/merge-2-or-more-rows-of-a-column-if-other-column-has-same-values-text-in-sql-ser